# How to LIMIT 1 per row that equals of the same value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

to put it simple, I'm using this SQL:

```
dbquery("SELECT * FROM lottery WHERE num = '1111' ");
```

I basically want to select all the rows from the table, where the number equals 1111, but the users will be able to insert as many lottery tickets as they want, which can even be the same number, but I only want to return 1 per user.

> LIMIT 1 WHERE `username` = 'Liam'

As a rough example, would this be possible? I'm not aware of any other methods that will work, from my knowledge.

Comment: change it to : **... WHERE username = 'Liam' LIMIT 1;**

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result! (Have you tried `SELECT DISTINCT username, num FROM ...`?)

Comment: But, I will be selecting multiple users VIA mysql_fetch_assoc, so I need to select every user, but I only want to grab one instance, since there could be a conflict where there are more than 1 row inserted by the same user.

Comment: "SELECT * FROM lottery WHERE num = '1111' group by username". You can try this.

Comment: What other columns does the table contain? Which of these must you show? Does any one or a combination of some uniquely identify a record in the table (e.g. an ID)?

Comment: @Shailesh Katarmal: Better not. This gives you arbitrarily chosen values that don't even have to belong to the same records. When using `GROUP BY`, use aggregation functions.

Comment: @ShaileshKatarmal, also, newer MySQL versions are stricter and don't support that invalid group by construction.

Comment: Basically, the table is (id, user_id, username, num)

Comment: And there can be multiple imputs from the same username (user_id is the identifier for the user), but I want to only read one per user in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
select distinct userid, username
from lottery
where num = '1111';
```

in order to get each user just once.

Comment: But what if the same user used the num "1111" more than once, then it'll be grabbing the instance again?

Comment: `DISTINCT` removes duplicate result rows. So no matter if a user has num 1111 once or twice or even more often, the user will be only once in the result. This is what you want, right?